# Symfony2 OnetoOne relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two class, User and PersonalData. We need relation OnetoOne with Doctrine in Symfony2. In my code I tried this relations, but in MySQL doesnt appear the foreign key. 
My code:

```
namespace TFC\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 */
/** @ORM\Entity */
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $email;
}

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * PersonalData
 */
/** @ORM\Entity */
class PersonalData
{

     /** @Id @OneToOne(targetEntity="User") */
    private $userId;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $firstName;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prefix with @ORM all your annotations like this:

```
@ORM\Id
@ORM\Column(type="integer")
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
```

This "[Unidirectional association](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional)" needs to be placed on `User` entity (because I think you want to load that informations from the User object...) and you don't need to care about the foreign key because doctrine create it automatically.

So place a `$personalData` property on `User` Entity and apply there the association, then delete `$userId` from `PersonalData` and add the `$id` property like did in `User`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the documentation claims that is not necessary have you tried something like:

```
@JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="id")
```

When you generate the entity do you get any message?

Comment: Database is created correctly, but I havent any foreign key

Comment: @CarlosSierra this is because `PersonalData` does not have an `$id` property.